# Date Field Search not filtering for 'dd/mm/yyyy' format - YII Framework

Tags: yii

CJUIDatePicker not filtering value for dd/mm/yyyy format but filtering if i gave DB date format manually like shown in image, I have attached all codes including View and Model for Search panel and Date Widget, Please look into this,

My Model Search(),

```
public function search()
    {
        // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('crm_base_contact_id',$this->crm_base_contact_id);
        $criteria->compare('name',$this->name,true);
        $Date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->created)); // get proper Y-m-d
        $startOfDay = $Date . ' 00:00:00'; // from start of the day
        $endOfDay = $Date . ' 23:59:59';   // until end of the day

// the rows between these
        $criteria->addBetweenCondition('created', strtotime($startOfDay) , strtotime($endOfDay) );

        $criteria->compare('createdby',$this->createdby,true);
        $criteria->compare('description',$this->description);
        $criteria->compare('is_active',$this->is_active);
        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }
```

My View for CGridView,

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'basecontact-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    //'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        array('class'=>'CButtonColumn',),
        'name',
        'crm_base_contact_id',      
                   array(
            'name'=>'is_active',
            'filter'=>CHtml::dropDownList('Event[is_active]', '',  
                array(
                    ''=>'',
                    '1'=>'Y',
                    '0'=>'N',
                )
            ),
            'value' =>'($data->is_active==1)?"Y":"N"',
        ),
        'created',
        'createdby',
        'description',
    ),
)); ?>
```

My View Code for Search column,

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker',array(
            'model'=>$model,
             'id'=>'Search-Created',
            'attribute'=>'created',
                        'options'=>array(
                     'dateFormat'=>'dd/mm/yy',
                     'showAnim'=>'fold',
                      'buttonImage'=>Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/images/icons.date.png',
                      'buttonImageOnly'=>true,
                      'buttonText'=>'',
                      'showAnim'=>'fold',
                      'showOn'=>'button',
                      'showButtonPanel'=>false,
            ),
));?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should probably change the date format. set it like this, 'dateFormat'=>'dd-mm-yy',

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
'model'=>$model,
'attribute'=>'dob',
// additional javascript options for the date picker plugin
'options' => array(
'showAnim' => 'fold',
'dateFormat'=>'dd/mm/yyyy',
),
'htmlOptions' => array(
'style' => 'height:20px;'
),
));
```

**Update:**

In your model, define it as following, in my case dob is the attribute name. you can have your own instead.

This will change your dateformat from "dd/mm/yyyy" to "yyyy-mm-dd internally before you run any find.

Ref : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#beforeFind-detail

```
protected function beforeFind()
{
$this->dob=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->dob)); 
parent::beforeFind();
}
```

**update 2**

Replace your search method with this,

```
public function search() {
    // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('crm_base_contact_id', $this->crm_base_contact_id);
    $criteria->compare('name', $this->name, true);    
    $criteria->compare('created', '07/12/2013'); //date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->created))
    $criteria->compare('createdby', $this->createdby, true);
    $criteria->compare('description', $this->description);
    $criteria->compare('is_active', $this->is_active);
    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria' => $criteria,
    ));
}
```

**Update 3**
change this line `$criteria->compare('created', '07/12/2013');` to

```
$criteria->compare('created', date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->created));
```

Comment: Yes i have set dateformat="dd/mm/yyyy" in CjuiDatePicker widget, its not filtering when i click date from widget in that format, if i enter "yyyy-mm-dd" format manually in CjuiDatePicker textfield and do search it filters . Please see attached image, and give me any idea

Comment: so why not change the dateformat to yyyy-mm-dd in CjuiDatePicker widget?

Comment: Check the updated answer and let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: I have included the CGridView widget code and CJuiDatePicker widget for Search date field, Please look into the above code and let me know what mistake i did

Comment: Yes its not working, My url turns to thishttp://www.example.com/ccvv7/index.php/baseContact/admin?BaseContactList[name]=&BaseContactList[created]=07%2F12%2F2013&yt36=Search                   It retuns grid empty after search

Comment: Ok i have posted the code in update 2. check it and let me know. since you already have a record to see if gets success i have hardcoded the string date. you can change it to date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->created)) after it work.

Comment: if i changed to "2013-12-07" instead of 07/12/2013  its working

Comment: this is strange. can you please share with me how you have storing created in database ? in which format?

Comment: it seems like your database contains values in following format. (Y-m-d) 2013-12-07

Comment: This should work for you now,     $criteria->compare('created', date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->created));

Comment: According to my knowledge, the above answer should work for you. now you can include the hh:mm:ss and give it a try. i.e $criteria->compare('created', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($this->created));